# Android simple view always sticking to the left

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In this simple view i want to have `CircleImageView` in right side of my view, but after compile project or adding other view inside that, this view always sticking to the left and removing left corner of that from left side don't resolve my problem

for example i want to have

[image]

but after adding some other view into container that always sticking to the left

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:funky="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_female_8"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/overlay_dark_10"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        funky:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        funky:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: u mean to say adding other view's to container your circular image view constraint's are changed??

Comment: @Anmol yes that always sticking to the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove start constraint in order to maintain the imageview in right -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:funky="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_female_8"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/overlay_dark_10"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also you can use layout_constraintHorizontal_bias -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:funky="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_female_8"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/overlay_dark_10"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use RelativeLayout also,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:funky="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff">

  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/circleImageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/photo_female_8"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/overlay_dark_10"
    app:civ_border_width="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     />
  </RelativeLayout>
```